# using ffmpeg.exe and java to get images from video

Tags: java, image, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a java function that given in input a video it generates a sets of images by seconds, so far this is what I've got:

public static void decodeAndCaptureFrames(String inputfilename, String outputfolder, int width, int height, double seconds) throws InputFormatException, EncoderException 
    {
        double duration = getVideoLenght(inputfilename);
        int index = 0;

```
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    for(double s = 0; s < duration; s+= seconds)
    {
        String outString = outputfolder + File.separator + index + ".png";
        String cmd = "ffmpeg.exe -i "+ inputfilename +" -f image2 -t 0.001 -ss "+ s +" -s "+ width +"x"+ height +" "+outString;

        try {
            Process p = runtime.exec(cmd);
            p.waitFor()
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("problema nell'esecuzione del runtime.exec");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(cmd);
        index++;
    }   
}
```

However the code is really slow and it only converts the first two images even if I get the print of the further images.
Since I'm using this external exe, can somebody tell me if I'm doing something wrong with the runtime and the process?
thanks.

Comment: Move `-ss` before `-i` so it becomes an input option. It is much faster (but can be less accurate). Use `-vframes 1` to get one frame instead of trying to declare a very short duration with `-t 0.001`. Use the [scale](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter instead of `-s` if you want to preserve the aspect: `-vf scale=320:-1`.

Comment: thanks! It's really much faster now, is there also a way to tell him to automatically overwrite a file if it's already there?

Comment: Use [`-y`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) as a [global option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis), or, conversely, use `-n` if you want ffmpeg to skip encoding a file if it exists.